# How to change the Date format 12/20/2014 to December 20, 2014

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

How to change the Date format 12/20/2014 to December 20, 2014  also if can you tell me if unknown to mm/dd/yyyy in android.

Hi the below code is working fine..

```
public static String setChangeDateFormat(String dateStr) {

        String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        String outputPattern = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

        Date date = null;
        String startDate = null; 

        try {
            date = inputFormat.parse(dateStr); 
            startDate = outputFormat.format(date);  
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return startDate; 
    }
```

Comment: @Duggu i'm passing the date as 12/20/2014 but answer is coming January 20, 2014, can you tell me how can i change the code as(December 20, 2014).

Answer (score 0):

Month denoted like below:-

```
Jan = 0, dec = 11
```

and you pass 12 so it shows by default January.
See below example :-

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

Read this document for more information :-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: the above code working fine...